# Changing ScrollingView's Font in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm developing my first app and there is a Activity which is the premade template for ScrollingView Activity. I want to change the font that the title is in (and I've tried virtually everything on StackOverflow including making new Themes, etc) but can't seem to get it working. Here is XML and Screenshot:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@font/joystix"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_mauve"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:title="hi"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@font/joystix"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_mauve">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your font in font directory of your resources and then set it on the collapsingToolbar like this:

```
Typeface tf = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font);
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(tf);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: you are wellcome